# Topology Proof with Neighborhoods and Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I am trying to prove this theorem:

> $A^o\cup A^{ext}\cup\ A^b=\mathbb{R}$

I don't really know where to start. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that $x\in\mathbb R$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb R$.

We discern the following statements:

- an open set $U$ exists with $x\in U\subseteq A$.
- an open set $U$ exists with $x\in U\subseteq A^c$.
- for every open set $U$ with $x\in U$ we have $U\cap A^c\neq\varnothing$ and $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$

Note that exactly one of these statements is true.

Answer (score 0):

I use more standard notions: $\overline{A}$ for closure, $A^e$ for exterior and $\partial A$ for boundary.

By definition
$$
\partial A = \overline{A}-A^o\quad\text{and }\quad A^e=\overline{A}^c
$$
Since $A^o\subset \overline{A}$
$$
\partial {A}\cup A^o=(\overline{A}-A^o)\cup A^o=(\overline{A}\cap A^{o^c})\cup A^o=(\overline{A}\cup A^o)\cap(A^{o^c}\cup A^o)=\overline{A}\cap \Bbb{R}=\overline{A}
$$
Thus
$$
\partial {A}\cup A^o\cup A^e=\overline{A}\cup\overline{A}^c=\Bbb{R}
$$